# Error overloading method using an enum - C# (Error CS0663)

Tags: c#, methods, enums, overloading

I've got an error and I can found on the web the reason. I have those three methods:

```
 public enum GO
 {
         thatGO, parent, child
 };

 public static void FadeOut(this GameObject go, float fadeTime)
 {
          Task t = new Task(FadeOut(go, fadeTime, false, GO.thatGO));
          new Task(TaskKiller(20f, t));
 }
 public static void FadeOut(this GameObject go, float fadeTime, bool destroy)
 {
          Task t = new Task(FadeOut(go, fadeTime, destroy, GO.thatGO));
          new Task(TaskKiller(20f, t));
 }
 public static void FadeOut(this GameObject go, float fadeTime, bool destroy, GO wichDestroy)
 {
          Task t = new Task(FadeOut(go, fadeTime, destroy, wichDestroy));
          new Task(TaskKiller(20f, t));
 }
```

The first 2 methods works fine, any error, but when I write the last (the one with an enum as a parameter), I get the error:

> error CS0663: Overloaded method `Extensions.FadeOut(this
>   UnityEngine.GameObject, float, bool, Extensions.GO)' cannot differ on
>   use of parameter modifiers only

I've been searching a lot on the internet and I can't understand why this error.
Any help will be welcome..

Edit:
I forgot to say that the method `FadeOut` from

```
Task t = new Task(FadeOut(go, fadeTime, destroy, wichDestroy));
```

is not the same as the method above. It's

```
public static IEnumerator FadeOut(GameObject go, float time, bool destroyGO, GO whatGO)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The code shown is not causing this error.

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: the line that causes the error is "public static void FadeOut(this GameObject go, float fadeTime, bool destroy, GO wichDestroy)"

Comment: sorr for spam y, Im new in the forum, I pressed return and I send the answer. The class is an static class with extension methods. I forgot to say that the method FadeOut from Task t = new Task(FadeOut(go, fadeTime, destroy, wichDestroy)); is not the same as the method above. Is "public static IEnumerator FadeOut(GameObject go, float time, bool destroyGO, GO whatGO)"

Uff, sorry for the mess, and thanks for the help guys. I'm using Unity. I discovered that if I change the order of the parameters the error dissapear, but I don't know why. Thanks again

Comment: @suzuka, move your additional explanation to the question with use of edit button.

Comment: @Vladislav done. Thanks again Vladislav :)

Comment: @suzuka, glad to help. But for future questions, it's better to use formatting possibilities provided by SO. At least for code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've understood from comments, you have instance method which differs only by return type from your extension method.
So the problem is that return type is not part of signature while overloading used.

Consider this case.

```
public int Foo() {}
public double Foo() {}

var num = Foo();
```

Which one should be called?
The same for out and ref parameters.

Comment: Argh.... What a mistake. Yes, you are right! Thank you so much! And thaks everyone for the instant help

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is deduced from t34t5 answer mentionning recursive calls.*

You can see that the static FadeOut method3 has exactly the same parameters than the FadeOut function called in Method 1 and 2.

There may be a conflict between the new static method 3 and a static / non static method called within method 1 and 2, probably returning a value (i.e. non "void").

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain better. The second FadeOut I called inside the methods is not the same. Its:
public static IEnumerator FadeOut(GameObject go, float time, bool destroyGO, GO whatGO){
....
}